# How to use more than 1 offering on revenuecat?

Tags: objective-c, swift, flutter, revenuecat

I am using revenuecat and I have a problem, I can't load my two products in my app (monthly and annual subsription) because only one is current, If I change the annual subscription to current I can load it but not the monthly . How can I use my two offering in my app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you need to either:

1. Add both products to the same Offering.

   > Offerings allow you to choose which combination of products are shown to a user on your paywall or upsell screen. For example your default Offering may contain a monthly and annual subscription, but you might want to experiment with Offerings with a different combination of subscription durations, trial lengths, prices, etc. (https://docs.revenuecat.com/docs/entitlements#section-offerings)
2. Access the "non-current" Offering directly through the Id, e.g. `offerings["my_offering_identifier"]`

   > In practice, you may not want to display the default current Offering to every user and instead have a specific cohort that see a different Offering.
   >   For example, displaying a higher priced Offering to users that came from paid acquisition to help recover ad costs, or a specific Offering designed to show iOS Subscription Offers when a user has cancelled their subscription.
   >   This can be accomplished with custom Offering identifiers (https://docs.revenuecat.com/docs/displaying-products#section-custom-offering-identifiers)